# Button on click and prompt a list of checkboxes to select and get selected value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button "Select Fruits", and on click of it , there will be a prompt box show all the fruits read from my database. When fruits are selected will show in div "selected_fruits_list".

The list of fruits I am able to read from my database, the problem now I am facing is how to create a prompt box with my list of "fruits" from my database, and show it in the div.

```
<button id="btn" type="button">Select Fruits</button>

foreach($obj3 as $note3){
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="fruitID[]" value='.$note3->fruitID.' >'.$note3->fruitName.'';
}

<div id="selected_fruits_list">
</div>
```

The list of fruits:
Apple, Banana, Mango, Orange, Watermelon

Seleted fruits : Apple, Orange

*The list of fruits may get 100 or 200, instead of 5. So I don't want all the fruits to be show, just showed what fruits is selected

Comment: Do you have any _specific_ problem?

Comment: try using select element, and populate fruits as its options https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: I dont know how to create a prompt box with the list of fruits with checkbox, and after select the fruits (Apple and Orange). The result I need to show in the div

Comment: why not use multi select? Or a <UL> list with checkboxes?

Comment: This is pretty basic. As a developer you should at least have an idea.

Comment: @DawidC because I this list of fruits it too big, I just need to show what is being selected, instead the of all the fruits

Comment: @Vohuman, sorry for that, because I found out that the list is too long and difficult to select, the example I show is just 5 of fruits, but the list will increase to be 100 or 200. If I am able to show the list in a prompt box and just display what is selected, I feed is more easy to view it

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of the selected checkboxes using `map()` and then `join()` it together when setting the `text()` of the div. Try this:

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    var checkedValues = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    $('#selected_fruits_list').text(checkedValues.join(', '));
});
```